# Program wchich reads its own size from st_size

Tags: c, linux, stat

Using stat() function and main function arguments I have to write a program which reads and prints its own size from st_size.
What I've already tried:

```
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h> 
int main( const char * szFileName ) 
{ 
  struct stat fileStat; 
  int err = stat( szFileName, &fileStat ); 
  if (0 != err) return 0; 
  return fileStat.st_size; 
}
```

But I don't realy understand how to edit it to read it's own size.

Thank you for your time and all the help :)

Comment: Offtopic: Please use slashes instead of backslashes in `#include` directives.

Comment: @andreee done :)

Comment: There are also some other problems with your code... please fix them first (hint: main arguments, use of '->', ...)

Comment: The arguments for `main` do not work like that, should be `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`. You also don't need to supply `program.exe` as an argument (previous edit): it is done for you as `argv[0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are some minor mistakes with your program, I have made a small effort to write a simple, working version:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUF 20

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  struct stat fileStat;
  char buf[BUF];
  int err;

  err = stat( argv[1], &fileStat ); // No argv sanity checks
  if (0 != err)
    return EXIT_FAILURE;

  memset(buf, 0, BUF);
  snprintf(buf, BUF, "%d\n", fileStat.st_size);
  write(0, buf, BUF);
}
```

Some further comments:

- `main(int argc, char** argv)` is the way to go for taking parameters. `argv[1]`contains the first argument, if provided `argv[0]` is the program name. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean).
- Do not return the size from main as this is reserved for returning error codes. Also, `return 0` means success in UNIX/Linux. By using `write`, you can also pipe the result for further processing.

To read the program's own size (as the OP requested), just compile (`gcc -o prog stat.c`) and run (`./prog prog`).

Comment: Thank you! Can you please add small description or just summarize how your program works? :)

EDIT:
Sorry i didn't see that you've already done it :D

Comment: Done! Please accept this as an answer if it worked for you. Thanks.

Comment: *Do not return the size from main as this is reserved for returning error codes.* Not only that - the return value of a function is likely limited in range to something like `0`-`255`.

Comment: @andreee Can you please describe what is this part doing? `memset(buf, 0, BUF);`